# Number 2 recognized as prime - explaining 2 modulus

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes, modulus

Can someone please explain why number 2 is also added to the list of prime numbers in the code below?

As the function below should only recognize a number as prime when there is at least 1 number with modulus not equal to 0.

As

```
2 % 0 = 0
2 % 1 = 0
```

That is why it should not be included, right?

```
def isprime(num1):
    for i in range(2, num1):
        if (num1 % i) == 0:
            return False
    return True


def getprimes(max_number):
    list_of_primes = []
    for i in range(2, max_number):
        if isprime(i):
            list_of_primes.append(i)
    return list_of_primes


def main():
    max_num_to_check = int(input('Enter the max limit: '))
    list_of_primes = getprimes(max_num_to_check)

    for i in list_of_primes:
        print(i)


main()
```

Comment: Well, 2 _is_ a prime number....

Comment: sorry tobias - but that is something that I am aware of - my question is related to the code

Comment: "As the function below should only recognize a number as prime when there is at least 1 number with modulus not equal to 0" Where do you read this from your code? The code (correctly) checks whether there is _no_ number with modulo equal to 0, which is the case for 2 (although it will not even check modulus 0 and 1, as the range starts at 2)

Comment: It's always good to remember that `range()` yields a right-side open interval.

Comment: 2 is a prime number.

Answer (score 0):

> As the function below should only recognize a number as prime when there is at least 1 number with modulus not equal to 0

It seems like you misunderstood how the prime check works. The `isprime` method actually checks whether there is *no* number with a modulus equal to zero. Also, it only checks *relevant* numbers, and that does not include `0` and `1`, since the modulus of *any* number with `1` is zero, and the modulus with `0` is actually not defined.

In the case of `2`, the function will check all numbers in `range(2, 2)`, which is empty, thus it (correctly) returns `True`. The function could be rewritten to this, maybe that's clearer:

```
def isprime(num1):
    return not any((num1 % i) == 0 for i in range(2, num1))
```

Comment: that was the lead I needed, thanks

the problem I have with understanding code is that I dont pay enough  attention to things like return and break - so for me I was always seeing 2 % 2 == 0 therefore return True ... but what it actually does is the condition is True therefore it steps a level above and return True ...